# jQuery clone() function not working properly

Tags: jquery

Check out my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JV8eU/

I have clone the `div` tag using jQuery `clone()` function

When someone click on "Add new" then new clone of `div` tag will be added, and when someone click on "Remove" then that `div` tag will be removed.

There is one problem with that, the original div tag also contain remove button, so someone click on it that time original div tag also removed.

I don't want to show that Remove link at the execution of code, when someone click add then the Remove link appear with the clone of the div tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/JV8eU/11/

You can dynamically add the remove div before adding new content.
 like this way: 
`obj.append('<div class="pull-left"><a href="#"onclick="removeDOM(this)">Remove</a></div>');`

Answer (score 3):

First of all in remove button div give that as hidden and in code make below changes...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Add").click(function(){
        $("#id").removeAttr("hidden");
        $("#id").show("slow");
        var obj =  $("div.content").eq(0).clone(); //this will clone the html elements
        $("div.row").append(obj); //this will append to the existing elements
    });
});
```

and in body..

```
<div class="pull-left"><a href="#" onclick='removeDOM(this)' id="id" hidden>Remove</a></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Always remember that when overriding default functionality, this is your friend:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

This JSFiddle seems to work nicely: http://jsfiddle.net/turiyag/JV8eU/9/
If you're looking to also maintain the initial element, this code would do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/turiyag/JV8eU/13/

Answer (score 0):

Put a template for the row in a separate element:

```
<div class="template">
  <div class="content">
    ...the row template goes here
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
</div>
```

Hide the template:

```
.template { display: none; }
```

Copy the row from the template once from the start, and when the link is clicked:

```
function copy() {
    $("div.row").append($(".template .content").clone());
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    copy();
    $("#Add").click(copy);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JV8eU/14/

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of better implementation. Instead of hiding the original one always, hide it conditionally.

[Here is JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulr/LpDNL/)

```
function removeDOM(thisObj){
if($('.content').size() == 2){
    $($('.remove-link').not(thisObj)[0]).hide();
}
if($('.content').size() != 1)
    $(thisObj).parent().parent().remove();
}
```

The benefit is, user can remove any row whichever he/she want.

Answer (score 0):

remove button form the html and append it whn button is clicked....

```
 var newRemoveButton ='<div class="pull-left"><a href="#" onclick='removeDOM(this)' id="id" hidden>Remove</a> </div>';
 $(newRemoveButton).appendTo(obj);
```

you can also have a look to this [link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/codes-to-create-addwith-remove-using.html) to add some effects.